# Is it possible to assign a default value when unpacking?

Tags: python, python-3.x, iterable-unpacking

I have the following:

```
>>> myString = "has spaces"
>>> first, second = myString.split()
>>> myString = "doesNotHaveSpaces"
>>> first, second = myString.split()
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
ValueError: need more than 1 value to unpack
```

I would like to have `second` default to `None` if the string does not have any white space. I currently have the following, but am wondering if it can be done in one line:

```
splitted = myString.split(maxsplit=1)
first = splitted[0]
second = splitted[1:] or None
```

Answer (score 31, accepted):

May I suggest you to consider using a different method, i.e. [`partition`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#str.partition) instead of `split`:

```
>>> myString = "has spaces"
>>> left, separator, right = myString.partition(' ')
>>> left
'has'
>>> myString = "doesNotHaveSpaces"
>>> left, separator, right = myString.partition(' ')
>>> left
'doesNotHaveSpaces'
```

If you are on python3, you have this option available:

```
>>> myString = "doesNotHaveSpaces"
>>> first, *rest = myString.split()
>>> first
'doesNotHaveSpaces'
>>> rest
[]
```

Comment: Is there a partition() equivalent that does not return the separator? it's pretty useless after all...

Comment: @mara004 Not as far as I know. The separator can be useful, to know afterward whether it was present or not (using `if not separator:` to handle the edge-case)

Answer (score 6):

A general solution would be to [`chain`](https://docs.python.org/3.5/library/itertools.html#itertools.chain) your iterable with a [`repeat`](https://docs.python.org/3.5/library/itertools.html#itertools.repeat) of `None` values and then use an [`islice`](https://docs.python.org/3.5/library/itertools.html#itertools.islice) of the result:

```
from itertools import chain, islice, repeat

none_repat = repeat(None)
example_iter = iter(range(1)) #or range(2) or range(0)

first, second = islice(chain(example_iter, none_repeat), 2)
```

this would fill in missing values with `None`, if you need this kind of functionality a lot you can put it into a function like this:

```
def fill_iter(it, size, fill_value=None):
    return islice(chain(it, repeat(fill_value)), size)
```

Although the most common use is by far for strings which is why [`str.partition`](https://docs.python.org/3.5/library/stdtypes.html?highlight=str.partition#str.partition) exists.

Answer (score 6):

Here's one general solution to unpack tuple and use default value if tuple is shorter than expected:

```
unpacker = lambda x,y=1,z=2:(x,y,z)

packed = (8,5)
a,b,c = unpacker(*packed)
print(a,b,c) # 8 5 2

packed = (8,)
a,b,c = unpacker(*packed)
print(a,b,c) # 8 1 2
```

[Play with this code](https://repl.it/@sytelus/unpacker)

Answer (score 0):

There are definitely some... uhh interesting answers here.

```py
def fixed_width_split(s: str, delim: str, n: int, fill: Any = None):
    raw_split = s.split(delim)

    return raw_split[:n] + [fill] * (n - len(raw_split))
```

Let's try it out:

```
>>> fixed_width_split("1:2:3", ":", 4)
['1', '2', '3', None]

>>> fixed_width_split("1:2:3", ":", 2)
['1', '2']

>>> fixed_width_split("1:2:3", ":", 5, fill=0)
['1', '2', '3', 0, 0]
```

So you can use it in the case where you need to unpack into a fixed number of values and be guaranteed that it will be able to unpack.

```py
a, b, c = fixed_width_split(mystr, ":", 3)
```

Some details on the somewhat obtuse syntax.

```
# take at most `n` elements from the original split.
parts[:n]

# make an array of x elements with value fill
[fill] * x 
[1] * 3 == [1, 1, 1]

# negative values are equivalent to 0.
[1] * -2 == []

# find the difference between the target length and the length of the original split.
n - len(parts)
```

Answer (score -1):

You could try this:

```
NUM2UNPACK=2   
parts = myString.split()    
first, second = parts+[None]*(NUM2UNPACK-(len(parts)))
```