# Split: ValueError: need more than 1 value to unpack python

Tags: python, split, user-input

I have the following part of code. When i give the value 'q' as input to x, I would like to stop the execution of the program.

```
di={}
while True:
 x,y=raw_input('Key, Value: ').split(',')
 a=int(x)
 di[a]=y
 if (x=='q'):
  break
 else
  continue
```

I get an error message that the input command cannot unpack because i gave only one argument. Any help?

```
Key, Value: 454,fds
Key, Value: 239,ada
Key, Value: q
Traceback (most recent call last);
File "tmp.py", line 3, in <module>
x,y=raw_input('Key,Value: ').split(',')
ValueError: need more than 1 value to unpack
```

I cannot write 'q' in both x and y.

Comment: Check if the input is equal to "q" _before_ you split it?

Comment: BTW, `else:  continue` at the bottom of a loop is pointless: the loop is going to continue anyway.

Comment: Fun fact: if you insist on smelly code, use `x, *y = input(...).....`, `y` is assigned to an empty list if there is no second argument.

Comment: @cᴏʟᴅsᴘᴇᴇᴅ The OP's using Python 2...

Comment: @Rawing if i check the input at the beginning, i will also get a message when i split it.

Comment: What do you mean? If you get a 'q' input, you break out of the loop, so the code doesn't try to split it. That's what I do in my answer...

Answer (score 1):

Your code snippet breaks, because you do tuple unpacking for which you require 2 values. Even if you could use q,q, your code would break, because you assign x to an int, which for the case of q would throw a ValueError.

Instead of using the tuple assignment you could use a list which you can check beforehand.

```
while True:
 alist =raw_input('Key, Value: ').split(',')

 if len(alist) is 1 or alist[0] is 'q':
    break

 x = int(alist[0])
 y = alist[1]
 di[x]=y
```

if you really want to use tuple have a look at this post.
[Is it possible to assign a default value when unpacking?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38666283/is-it-possible-to-assign-a-default-value-when-unpacking)

Answer (score 0):

If the input string doesn't contain `','` then `split(',')` returns a list with a single element, which will cause `x, y = []` to return the aforementioned error.

Answer (score 0):

You just need to reorganize your logic slightly. Test if the 'q' quit string has been given, and break out of the loop if it has. Otherwise, split the string, and insert the data into the dictionary. It's a good idea to permit both 'q' and 'Q' for the quit signal. And it's also a good idea to strip off stray whitespace from the value you're storing in the dict. You don't need to worry about that for the key since `int` will ignore leading & trailing whitespace when converting a string.

Here's a cleaned up version of your code.

```
di = {}
print 'Enter q to quit'
while True:
    s = raw_input('Key, Value: ')
    if s.lower() == 'q':
        break
    x, y = s.split(',')
    di[int(x)] = y.strip()

print di
```

**demo**

```
Enter q to quit
Key, Value: 1, a
Key, Value: 2 , b
Key, Value:  3 , c
Key, Value: q
{1: 'a', 2: 'b', 3: 'c'}
```